# Writing text blocks using nested iteration in Vim

Tags: vim, nested-loops

Let's say I'd like to write a 5x5 text block, such as

```
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
```

And I want to do it using nested iteration.
In pseudocode it would look like

```
do five times ((do five times (type 'a')) change line)
```

So my first guess was to simply convert that as

```
5 ((5 (i a esc)) enter)
```

But I can't do that, because Vim doesn't support use of parentheses for specifying execution order. And simply typing

```
5 5 i a esc enter
```

will of course not work, since that will just produce a single line with 55 'a's and a newline.

So my question is: Is there a way to write text blocks using nested iteration in Vim? I know that there are other ways to write text blocks, but I want to know if this is possible, just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly, you need to use a register, expression, or macro:

```
qq5aa<Esc>a<CR><Esc>q4@q
```

- `qq` - record macro
- `5aa<Esc>` - insert 5 `a`'s
- `a<CR><Esc>` - insert line break
- `q4@q` - stop recording, repeat 4 more times

Comment: Save precious key strokes:  `qq5aa<CR><Esc>q4@q`.

Comment: @benjifisher: Wouldn't that insert 5 lines with an `a` each, instead of a single line with 5 `a`s?!

Answer (score 1):

I do not normally like one-liners, but this seems to work:

```
:for i in range(5) | for j in range(5) | execute 'normal ia' | endfor | execute "normal A\<CR>" | endfor
```

and this is a lot shorter:

```
:for i in range(5) | execute 'normal 5aa' | put='' | endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<esc> i a <esc> x 5p dd 5P
```

- esc  - switch to normal mode
- i     - switch to insert mode
- a     - print "a"
- esc   - switch to normal mode
- x     - deleta "a"
- 5p    - paste a 5 times ("aaaaa")
- dd    - delete line "aaaaa"
- 5P    - paste line "aaaaa" 5 times

Answer (score 0):

```
:norm 5oaaaaa
```

is the simplest way I could think of to obtain a 5x5 matrix of `a`'s but I don't think it satisfies your curiosity.

One could also do:

```
:norm Oaaaaa
5@:
```

but that's not really recursive either.

So… I don't know!